# MySQL Subquery returns more than 1 row. How to find subquery?

Tags: mysql

this is the one of common errors when one of your sub-queries returns more than 1 row. Is there easy way to locate that sub-query? I have a script with ~500 line of codes and about 20 sub-queries.

Can I easy locate which one returns more than one row without checking every sub-query manually?

Kind regards

Comment: add a **LIMIT 1** at the end of each subquery. so you can findout which query returns more rows

Comment: if you need all the result You can also use an IN Clause

Comment: I know about LIMIT, I asked actually about getting more verbose info about error without putting LIMIT in every one sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I easy locate which one returns more than one row without checking
>   every sub-query manually

NO, even if you don't run the subqueries manually one by one, you will at least have to go through your script code and see which subquery can return more than one row.

There is no short cut to it present.